# Find the greatest common divisor of the following polynomials in Z5[x].

Tags: abstract-algebra

[image]

After I do the division algorithm, I get
$x^4 + x^3 +3x= x (x^3 + x^2 -2) +5x$

Since $5$ is congruent to $0$ $(mod$  $5)$, does it imply that the remainder is $0$?
So the gcd is $b(x)$?

Comment: Note:  $b(x)=[1]_5x^3+[1]_5x^2+[3]_5$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, or you could say simply $b(x)=[1]_5x^3+[1]_5x^2+[3]_5$,

and then it's obvious that $a(x)=xb(x)$.